# JQuery UI Datepicker date format issue with initial value

Tags: jquery, date, format, datepicker

I need to set the initial date for the date picker to 03/20/2010 in mm-dd-yyyyy format.
I have done this

```
<input id='datepicker' type='text' value='20/03/2010' />
```

But my problem is on clicking the field date picker populates with today's date as highlighed and no date selected, and up on selecting date value

But when i change my input field like one below

```
<input id='datepicker' type='text' value='03/20/2010' />
```

Date picker  is populating March 20 as selected date and current date highlighted. But all in 'mm-dd-yyyy' format!

I want show all dates in 'dd-mm-yyyy' format. How can I solve this?

I tried some of the options and combinations below, but none of them solved my problem

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
$("#datepicker").datepick({dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy'});
$("#datepicker").formatDate('dd/mm/yy');
$('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", new Date($("#datepicker").val()) );
```

Update:
Unfortunately i cant set Date value march 20 directly via javascript sice it is dynamically changing and is stored in a PHP variable. I need to get the default value from input field itself.

Comment: looking at your code i have changed my code to $("#datepicker").datepicker();$('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", new Date($("#datepicker").val()) ); and it help me

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'dd-mm-yy');
```

Year is specified as `y` for 2 digits and `yy` for 4 digits, as stated [here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate).

Comment: Somehow only this snippet worked for me. This had no effect `$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"});`

Answer (score 8):

You need a combination of `dateFormat` and `defaultDate` options:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker(
{
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    defaultDate: '20/03/2010'
});
```

there are, however, many different ways to specify the default date. I'm not sure what you need so you can reference the API here: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-defaultDate.

Comment: Thanks man, But Unfortunately i cant set Date value march 20 directly via javascript sice it is dynamically changing and is stored in a PHP variable. I need to get the default value from input field itself.

Comment: Well, you can read that out of the input yourself: `defaultDate: $('#datePicker').val()`.

Answer (score 0):

`mm` equals minutes not months.
Use `dd/MM/yyyy` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Also remember that `type="date"` will make issue, so set `type` as `text`.

Answer (score -5):

Not accurate!!!

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker(
{
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    defaultDate: '20/03/2010'
});
```

You must to put the right format in dateFormat : for your example there is : `dd/mm/yy`
two mistake:

- day/month inversion
- year is only two 'y' not four