# How can I change the format of my formbuilder DateType field (Symfony 4)?

Tags: php, symfony, date, datepicker, formbuilder

This is how I create my datepicker field:

```
  $formBuilder->add('getTimestamp', DateType::class, array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
            'data' => new \DateTime(),
            'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'line-height: 20px;'), 'label' => $field['fieldName'],
          ));
```

[image]

When I change the format...

```
$formBuilder->add('getTimestamp', DateType::class, array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'line-height: 20px;'), 'label' => $field['fieldName'],
          ));
```

... the date is formatted correctly, but the datepicker ist not working anymore.

[image]

Comment: use `'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',` not `'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',`

Comment: @DEarTh But then I do not have the correct format. I need `26.12.2018`otherwise people do not understand it (https://www.toytowngermany.com/forum/topic/70364-how-the-date-is-written-in-germany/)

Comment: Then change the date format in `datepicker` ref [datepicker change date format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2427630/8317643)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this: [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Mainly, there is a difference between "Over the wire" and "Presentation" format. In your case, the format you are configuring is "Over the wire". You should probably look at specifying a "Presentation" format in your front-end (e.g. the HTML date input, or jquery UI plugin, etc.